# Why the backgournd of a layout affect that of a EditText inside the layout?

Tags: android, background, android-linearlayout

I add a EditText into a Linearlayout, for each ,I set a picture as background. But the background of the Linearlayout affect that of the EditText, the code are as follows :

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
    android:background="@drawable/layout_bg" 
    > 

    <EditText     
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="@drawable/input" 
        android:inputType="text" 
        android:paddingLeft="4dp" 
        android:layout_margin="4dp" 
        /> 
    </LinearLayout>
```

The layout_bg affect the input，but when I set the backgournd of the LinearLayout #F9F9F9, the background of Linearlayout will not affect that of EditText . Why did this happen ?

I am newly here , I can not upload an image right now .
The result is above , the color of the outer background is blue, but the color of the background of EditText is white, I want the inner background makes sense , How should I make it ?

Comment: Oh my God, just now , I found that the background of EditText does no t make sense .

Comment: No， the background of the LinearLayout affect that of EditText , the latter does not work .

Comment: i didnt get you!! how does it affects the edittext ??

Comment: the color of the outer background is blue , the color of the inner backbroudn is white , the result is that I can not see the inner background , the whole linerlayout is blue !

Comment: you mean that you have  background of linear layout is blue and for edittext is white.but you are getting the blue color for edittext ?? am i right ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved , I can't see the inner background , cause it is transparent !

Comment: It's totally my fault. I didn't check the original picture , so when the result was out of my expection , I thought something was wrong , but actually It costed me a lot of time ! Oh my god !